# Membership cannot be saved

Tags: drupal, civimember

> The membership cannot be saved because the status cannot be calculated
>   for start_date: 20160425 end_date 20170424 join_date 20160425 as at
>   2017-09-25 13:54:10

This error message shows when a user, with recorded start and end dates of membership in expired status tries to renew their membership.

Perhaps status rules need some work or there is an issue with memberships that occurred before upgrading to 4.7.x version of the CRM. Here is a screenshot of the status settings:

[image: New]

[image: Current]

[image: Grace]

[image: Expired]

Note: I know this may be a duplicate question but I wanted to provide more information than than the other posts to see if we can resolve all of them.

Using CiviCRM 4.7.15 on Drupal 7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do your Status settings you need to ensure that all the options are set so they are contiguous. This should avoid any problems with dates not fitting in to the expected 'flow'.

Answer (score 1):

The issue went away once I adjusted the membership rules.

I disabled Grace because we want users to renew right away. I changed the expired rule so that the start of the event is the end date and the end of the event is not selected. See screenshot.

[image: Expired]

Comment: yep. from screenshots your expired status looked incorrectly set too.

Comment: As i read your screenshot in the question you have the Expired running from 1 month after to 1 day after which is a bit non-sensical. The one in this answer doesn't show that. Key thing is to double check your periods are all contiguous

Comment: eg your Current isn't set to start asap after the New period ends. Suggest you take a look at a demo site where I would hope it is all correct

Comment: I brought over a CRM from our website and just discovered these settings. It's all good now!

Comment: I will try and summarise as an answer then